# Long multi-byte NOPs: commonly understood macros or other notation

Tags: assembly, x86-64, naming-conventions, disassembly, no-op

It's not a big secret that x86 (and x86_64) processors have not only the single-byte `NOP` instruction, but also various types of multi-byte NOP-like instructions.

These are the ones I've managed to find:

Recommended by AMD, ref. [AMD Software Optimization Guide for AMD Family 15h Processors, document #47414](http://support.amd.com/TechDocs/47414_15h_sw_opt_guide.pdf), section 5.8 "Code Padding with Operand-Size Override and Multibyte NOP", page 94)

```
90                              NOP1_OVERRIDE_NOP
6690                            NOP2_OVERRIDE_NOP
0f1f00                          NOP3_OVERRIDE_NOP
0f1f4000                        NOP4_OVERRIDE_NOP
0f1f440000                      NOP5_OVERRIDE_NOP
660f1f440000                    NOP6_OVERRIDE_NOP
0f1f8000000000                  NOP7_OVERRIDE_NOP
0f1f840000000000                NOP8_OVERRIDE_NOP
660f1f840000000000              NOP9_OVERRIDE_NOP
66660f1f840000000000            NOP10_OVERRIDE_NOP
6666660f1f840000000000          NOP11_OVERRIDE_NOP
```

Recommended by Intel, ref. [Intel 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer's Manual Volume 2B: Instruction Set Reference, N-Z](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-vol-2b-manual.pdf), section "NOP"

```
90                              NOP
6690                            66 NOP
0f1f00                          NOP DWORD ptr [EAX]
0f1f4000                        NOP DWORD ptr [EAX + 00H]
0f1f440000                      NOP DWORD ptr [EAX + EAX*1 + 00H]
660f1f440000                    66 NOP DWORD ptr [EAX + EAX*1 + 00H]
0f1f8000000000                  NOP DWORD ptr [EAX + 00000000H]
0f1f840000000000                NOP DWORD ptr [EAX + EAX*1 + 00000000H]
660f1f840000000000              66 NOP DWORD ptr [EAX + EAX*1 + 00000000H]
```

GNU assembler (in binutils / gas) [includes the following patterns](https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=blob_plain;f=gas/config/tc-i386.c;hb=HEAD):

f32 (older Intel-compatible CPUs up to Pentium):

```
90                              nop
6690                            xchg %ax,%ax
8d7600                          leal 0(%esi),%esi
8d742600                        leal 0(%esi,1),%esi
908d742600                      nop; leal 0(%esi,1),%esi
8db600000000                    leal 0L(%esi),%esi
8db42600000000                  leal 0L(%esi,1),%esi
908db42600000000                nop; leal 0L(%esi,1),%esi
89f68dbc2700000000              movl %esi,%esi; leal 0L(%edi,1),%edi
8d76008dbc2700000000            leal 0(%esi),%esi; leal 0L(%edi,1),%edi
8d7426008dbc2700000000          leal 0(%esi,1),%esi; leal 0L(%edi,1),%edi
8db6000000008dbf00000000        leal 0L(%esi),%esi; leal 0L(%edi),%edi
8db6000000008dbc2700000000      leal 0L(%esi),%esi; leal 0L(%edi,1),%edi
8db426000000008dbc2700000000    leal 0L(%esi,1),%esi; leal 0L(%edi,1),%edi
```

alt (for modern CPUs, same for Intel & AMD):

```
0f1f00                          nopl (%[re]ax)
0f1f4000                        nopl 0(%[re]ax)
0f1f440000                      nopl 0(%[re]ax,%[re]ax,1)
660f1f440000                    nopw 0(%[re]ax,%[re]ax,1)
0f1f8000000000                  nopl 0L(%[re]ax)
0f1f840000000000                nopl 0L(%[re]ax,%[re]ax,1)
660f1f840000000000              nopw 0L(%[re]ax,%[re]ax,1)
662e0f1f840000000000            nopw %cs:0L(%[re]ax,%[re]ax,1)
```

alt_short (for modern AMD family CPUs):

```
0f1f440000660f1f440000          nopl 0(%[re]ax,%[re]ax,1); nopw 0(%[re]ax,%[re]ax,1)
660f1f440000660f1f440000        nopw 0(%[re]ax,%[re]ax,1); nopw 0(%[re]ax,%[re]ax,1)
660f1f4400000f1f8000000000      nopw 0(%[re]ax,%[re]ax,1); nopl 0L(%[re]ax)
0f1f80000000000f1f8000000000    nopl 0L(%[re]ax); nopl 0L(%[re]ax)
0f1f80000000000f1f840000000000  nopl 0L(%[re]ax); nopl 0L(%[re]ax,%[re]ax,1)
```

alt_long (for modern Intel family CPUs):

```
66662e0f1f840000000000          data16; nopw %cs:0L(%[re]ax,%[re]ax,1)
6666662e0f1f840000000000        data16; data16; nopw %cs:0L(%[re]ax,%[re]ax,1)
666666662e0f1f840000000000      data16; data16; data16; nopw %cs:0L(%[re]ax,%[re]ax,1)
66666666662e0f1f840000000000    data16; data16; data16; data16; nopw %cs:0L(%[re]ax,%[re]ax,1)
6666666666662e0f1f840000000000  data16; data16; data16; data16; data16; nopw %cs:0L(%[re]ax,%[re]ax,1)
```

My question is the following: is there any widespread / common naming for all these byte sequences, as macros, pseudo-mnemonics, or anything like that? So far I've only found that:

- AMD recommends to name them `NOPx_OVERRIDE_NOP` (`x` = byte length).
- gas understands `nopw` (as 2 byte nop) and `nopl` (as 4 byte nop)

How modern disassemblers tend to output these values?

Related, but not duplicate question: [What does NOPL do in x86 system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12559475/what-does-nopl-do-in-x86-system)

Comment: They are usually emitted by alignment directives, because most of the time the programmer is interested in getting to a particular aligned address and doesn't care or know how many bytes that will be from the current location.

Comment: @Jester, could you name some alignment directives / assemblers that reliably give these NOP paddings? So far I've found out that normal `align` pads with 0s (and that's perfectly understandable - you won't want to pad with anything else in non-code section, for example). So far I've found only [nasm feature request](http://sourceforge.net/p/nasm/feature-requests/69/) about proposed `calign` directive to do that, but as far as I can see it never seen the light of the day.

Comment: In `GAS` all the alignment directives (`.align`, `.p2align`, `.balign`) work like this when used in code sections. As you said, `nasm` seems to be missing this feature.

Comment: This is an old question, but I just encountered one of these long nop instructions generated by Visual Studio, for C / C++ code that flows into a loop. The nop is used to pad the code so that the loop branch target is on a 16 byte boundary (in the case I saw, it happened to be a 32 byte boundary).

Comment: Intel X86 Encoder/Decoder a.k.a. XED, which is kind of an official Intel tool for x86 encodings, defines long NOPs  here: https://github.com/intelxed/xed/blob/b53f33e44dd2e5fb2e63f9c0e35c65b72c933dae/src/enc/xed-encode.c#L460 . Strangely enough, only 1 to 9 bytes long NOPs are supported.

Comment: An analysis of patterns in real binaries:
https://gist.github.com/stevemk14ebr/d117e8d0fd1432fb2a92354a034ce5b9

Comment: EuroAssembler uses long NOPs in code section for implicit or explicit alignment with mnemonics `NOP1`, `NOP2`, .. `NOP9`, see https://euroassembler.eu/eadoc/#InsEnhNOP

Answer (score 4):

Recent GAS in binutils has a `.nops N` pseudo-instruction that expands to the requested number of bytes for the target:

- [**`.nops`** *`size`*`[,` *`control`*`]`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Nops.html)