# x86 multi-byte NOP and instruction prefix

Tags: assembly, x86, prefix, instruction-encoding, no-op

As a small recall, the x86 architecture defines `0x0F 0x1F [mod R/M]` as a multi-byte NOP.

Now I'm looking at the specific case of an 8-byte NOP: I have got

```
0x0F 0x1F 0x84 0x__ 0x__ 0x__ 0x__ 0x__
```

where the last 5 bytes have got arbitrary values.

The third byte, `[mod R/M]`, split up gives:

[image: modrm]

- `mod = 10b`: argument is `reg1` + a DWORD-sized displacement
- `reg2 = 000b`: (we don't care)
- `reg1 = 100b`: indicates that the argument is instead the `SIB` byte + a DWORD-sized displacement.

Now, as a concrete example, if I take

```
0x0F 0x1F 0x84 0x12 0x34 0x56 0x78 0x9A
```

I've got

- `SIB = 0x12`
- `displacement = 0x9A785634`: a DWORD

Now I add the `0x66` instruction prefix to indicate that the displacement should be a WORD instead of a DWORD:

```
0x66 0x0F 0x1F 0x84 0x12 0x34 0x56 0x78 0x9A
```

I expect `0x78 0x9A` to be 'cut off' and be treated as a new instruction. However, when compiling this and running `objdump` on the resulting executable, it still uses all 4 bytes (a DWORD) as displacement.

Am I misunderstanding the meaning of 'displacement' in this context? Or does the `0x66` prefix not have any effect on multi-byte NOP instructions?

Comment: The 0x66 prefix does not affect the size of the displacement - only the operand size.

Comment: So, if the components of an instructions are: Prefix, Opcode, Mod R/M, SIB, Displacement, Immediate, then 0x66 affects the *Immediate* value? Alright, it kind of makes sense: the multi-byte NOP does not take an immediate value, and thus 0x66 does not have any effect. Thank you!

Comment: Related: [Long multi-byte NOPs: commonly understood macros or other notation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25545470/427158)

Answer (score 8):

The `66H` prefix overrides the size of the operand to 16 bit.
It does not override the size of the address, if you want that you use `67H`.  (But don't in 32-bit code; that tends to cause an [LCP stall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65530097/does-a-length-changing-prefix-lcp-incur-a-stall-on-a-simple-x86-64-instruction/65572595#65572595), especially if you use `nopw [bx+0x1111]` with a disp16 instead of the disp32 you'd get from the same ModRM encoding without a `67H` prefix.)

Here's a list of all traditional x86 prefixes (not REX or VEX/EVEX).

```
        F0h = LOCK  -- locks memory reads/writes
      String prefixes
        F3h = REP, REPE  
        F2h = REPNE      
      Segment overrides
        2Eh = CS
        36h = SS
        3Eh = DS
        26h = ES
        64h = FS
        65h = GS
      Operand override 
        66h. Changes size of data expected to 16-bit
      Address override 
        67h. Changes size of address expected to 16-bit (in 32-bit mode)
```

---

However it is best not to create your own NOP instructions, but stick to the recommended (multi-byte) NOPs.

AMD recommend the following:
*Table 4-9. Recommended Multi-Byte Sequence of NOP Instruction*

```
bytes  sequence                encoding

 1      90H                            NOP
 2      66 90H                         66 NOP
 3      0F 1F 00H                      NOP DWORD ptr [EAX]
 4      0F 1F 40 00H                   NOP DWORD ptr [EAX + 00H]
 5      0F 1F 44 00 00H                NOP DWORD ptr [EAX + EAX*1 + 00H]
 6      66 0F 1F 44 00 00H             NOP DWORD ptr [AX + AX*1 + 00H]
 7      0F 1F 80 00 00 00 00H          NOP DWORD ptr [EAX + 00000000H]
 8      0F 1F 84 00 00 00 00 00H       NOP DWORD ptr [AX + AX*1 + 00000000H]
 9      66 0F 1F 84 00 00 00 00 00H    NOP DWORD ptr [AX + AX*1 + 00000000H]
```

(The disassembly in this table is wrong: it shows `[AX]` in the instructions that use a `66H` prefix.  That prefix sets the *operand*-size to 16, but the address-size is unmodified. And AX isn't encodeable in a 16-bit addressing mode if this was using a `67H` prefix in 32-bit mode.  And 16-bit address size would mean a 2-byte displacement not 4-byte, and removes the possibility of a SIB byte.  This is part of why `67H` is slow to decode in 32-bit mode on Intel CPUs, giving [false LCP stalls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65530097/does-a-length-changing-prefix-lcp-incur-a-stall-on-a-simple-x86-64-instruction/65572595#65572595).)

Intel does not mind up to 3 redundant prefixes, so nop's up to 11 bytes can be constructed like so.

```
 10     66 66 0F 1F 84 00 00 00 00 00H     NOP DWORD ptr [AX + AX*1 + 00000000H] 
 11     66 66 66 0F 1F 84 00 00 00 00 00H  NOP DWORD ptr [AX + AX*1 + 00000000H]
```

---

You can also **eliminate NOPs by prefixing normal instructions with redundant prefixes**.  e.g.

```
rep mov reg,reg //one extra byte
```

`rep` is normally ignored, but new CPU extension often use `rep` to make an old opcode mean something different.  A safer choice is a prefix that *can* be valid for that opcode, but has no effect on register operands, like a segment override.  Or like a `DS` prefix when that's already the default, or in 64-bit mode where CS/DS/ES/SS bases are all 0.

Or choosing registers that need a REX prefix, so the assembler must use longer versions of the same instruction.

```
test r8d,r8d is one byte longer than: test edx,edx
```

The instructions with immediate operands have short and long versions (except for `test`).

```
and edx,7        //short imm8
and edx,0000007  //long imm32
```

Most assembler will helpfully shorten all instructions for you, so you'll have to code the longer instructions yourself using `db`, or NASM/YASM `and edx, strict dword 7`.  See *[What methods can be used to efficiently extend instruction length on modern x86?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48046814/what-methods-can-be-used-to-efficiently-extend-instruction-length-on-modern-x86)* for more about this in general.

Interspersing these in strategic locations can help you align jump targets without having to incur delays due to the decoding or execution of a NOP.

Remember on most CPUs executing NOPs still uses up resources. Front-end decode / uop-cache / issue slots, and tracking it in the ROB until retirement.  Padding other instructions takes up the same extra I-cache space, but without those other costs.

These techniques of extending instructions sometimes get used automatically, when you enable workarounds for the performance pot-hole introduced by Intel's microcode workaround for the JCC erratum in Skylake: see [How can I mitigate the impact of the Intel jcc erratum on gcc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61256646/how-can-i-mitigate-the-impact-of-the-intel-jcc-erratum-on-gcc)  This can require extending instructions *inside* inner loops, where you really don't want to use a NOP, so Intel recommended extending earlier instructions.

Comment: The [yasm docs](http://www.tortall.net/projects/yasm/manual/html/manual.html#nasm-immediate) say you can write `add rax, dword 1` to force a 32bit immediate instead of imm8, but it doesn't work in practice.  (Still shortened to imm8 with `yasm 1.3.0` from the Ubuntu package.)  Also, you can pad with a REX prefix even if the instruction doesn't need one (without changing registers).  `db 0x40` / `test edx,edx` still decodes as `test edx,edx`.  A REX with no bits set only changes the meaning of an insn that uses AH/BH/CH/DH.  (To SIL, etc, in some order I'd have to look up)

Comment: Update: YASM: `add rax, strict dword 1` forces a 32-bit immediate.   NASM:   `add rax, strict qword 1` forces a 32-bit immediate.  NASM and YASM each choke on the other one, complaining about sizes.  But anyway, `strict` is the essential keyword in NASM syntax for immediates and addressing-mode displacements.

Comment: I recommend to avoid using `rep` prefixes where not defined already as Intel tends to give them new meanings later on.  For example, `rep mov` has a meaning within Intel HLE now.

Comment: @fuz: On the other hand, rep imul is a fun one.